# how to get in gwt the current position?

Tags: gwt

we have this example: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation

which shows how to get the user's position in JSP code.
How to use it using GWT?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GWT runs JavaScript in the browser, you'll have to look into using the brand-new [HTML5 Geolocation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) features to make this work.

In fact, the [gwt-mobile-webkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/) project includes Geolocation features in GWT (targeted at mobile webkit browsers like the one on Android and the iPhone).

If that doesn't fit your needs exactly, you can always have GWT call the necessary native JS code using [JSNI](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html).